# Logging from a C program on boot

Tags: c, linux, boot

I have a C program running on raspberry pi boot from `/etc/rc.local`:

```
bash -c 'MY_PATH/MY_FILE > /MY_PATH/MY_LOG_FILE 2>&1' &
```

Is this correct to write a log file from the C program when the raspberry pi boots?

Answer (score 0):

Using the April 2022 raspbian, I tested both [console/lite](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2022-04-07/2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz) and [Desktop](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2022-04-07/2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img.xz) Raspios.

Added this line to /etc/rc.local:

```
bash -c '/usr/bin/uname > /tmp/MY_LOG_FILE 2>&1' &
```

Rebooted, and check the log:

```
$ cat /tmp/MY_LOG_FILE
Linux
```

Both confirmed working.